# useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. react-router-dom version 6.12.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

> `useNavigate()` may be used only in the context of a `<Router>`
> component.

`react-router-dom` version is ^6.12.0.

As shown above, we have a problem.
What do you recommend to do?

Header

Merchant button on navbar is not working when it is clicked.

See my code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./css/header.css";
import { Menu } from "antd";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const items = [
  { label: "Merchants", path: <Link to="/merchant" />, key: "merchant" },
  { label: "Customers", path: <Link to="/customer" />, key: "customer" },
];

const Header = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleMenuClick = ({ key }) => {
    if (key) {
      console.log(key)
      navigate(key);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="cc-nav">
      <div className="cc-nav-body">
        <Menu
          defaultSelectedKeys={["/merchant"]}
          mode="horizontal" items={items}
          onClick={handleMenuClick}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

routes.js file

```js
import React from "react";
const Dashboard = React.lazy(() => import('../containers/TheContent'));
const Merchant = React.lazy(() => import('../pages/merchant/pages/Merchant'));

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
  { path: '/merchant', name: 'Merchant', element: <Merchant /> },
]

export default routes;
```

App.js file

```
import 'antd/dist/antd';
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import './App.css';
import TheLayout from "./containers/TheLayout";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './router/routes';

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <ConfigProvider
             theme={{token: {
                colorPrimary: "#3b2eed"
              }}}
        >
          <TheLayout>
              <BrowserRouter>
                  <Suspense>
                      <Routes>
                          {routes.map(route => {
                              return <Route
                                  key={route.path}
                                  path={route.path}
                                  name={route.name}
                                  element={route.element}
                              />
                          })}
                      </Routes>
                  </Suspense>
              </BrowserRouter>
          </TheLayout>
        </ConfigProvider>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to add this button that goes back to the previous page using `react-router-dom` but I get the above error, and also all the components on my website disappear.

Comment: In case you just missed it, or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (*you earn a badge, BTW*), there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error I'm guessing you are rendering the `Header` component in the `TheLayout` component which is outside the routing context provided by the `BrowserRouter`.

Move `BrowserRouter` higher in the ReactTree such that all `react-router-dom` routes, links, hooks have the routing context available to them.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> // <-- render higher in tree
      <div className="App">
        <ConfigProvider
          theme={{
            token: {
              colorPrimary: "#3b2eed"
            }
          }}
        >
          <TheLayout> // <-- than components that may need routing context
            <Suspense>
              <Routes>
                {routes.map(route => (
                  <Route key={route.path} {...route} />
                ))}
              </Routes>
            </Suspense>
          </TheLayout>
        </ConfigProvider>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```